# Vuejs router how reload a javascript plugin

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm new with VueJS and I don't find a solution to my issue.

I use a jquery plugin, [zoomslider](https://github.com/mingyeungs/jquery-zoomslider) that is load in main.js inside the mounted function.

My website is multi-page and i use the router plugin to switch around, but when I back on the page where i use **zoomslider**,

the plugin don't reload, i think the problem is because zoomslider is loaded when DOM is ready, how can reload the plugin?

Or better where is the best practice for loading globally an external plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `$(yourElement).zoomSlider()` to load the plugin on a new element!

You can select one element, or multiple ones, inside the `$` function.

Comment: In this way work, but I've another effect of another plugin, some effect with bootstrap 3 too, I need doing this method for all the element?
Isn't possible reload the page with all javascript?
Sorry for the noob question.
However, I thank you first

Comment: You have to reload every plugin for your elements, with the method I wrote. But instead of zoomSlider, it's going to be the name of the plugin!